# jquery UI Dialog - Whenever opening a dialog, make sure all others are closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an app that has multiple UI Dialogs... How can I smartly make sure you can't open 2 dialogs. So whenever you open a Dialog it closes any currently open UI Dialogs.

Answer (score 8):

All dialogs get the `ui-dialog-content` class added, so you can just do this when opening your dialog:

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
$("#myDialog").dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jquery-ui dialog, you should be able to use something similar to $(".selectorClass").dialog("destroy") to reset all dialogs back to their original (hidden) states. *(Making sure to put in your own selector class/ID of course!)*

For more information, check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't want to actually restrict users' ability to open more than one dialog by making each dialog modal (so they can't click anywhere on the page until the dialog is deliberately closed), I would say you want to cache your dialogs in a variable and then iterate through this array to close them all before opening the target.  Without testing what I'm writing here, try something along these lines:

```
var options = {
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    ...
};

var dlg = $('dialog-candidate-' + n);

$(dlg).each(function(i) {
    $(this).dialog(options);
    $('#dialog-trigger-' + n).click(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i<= dlg.length; i++) {
          dlg[0].dialog("close");
        }
        $(this).dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
    n++;
});
```